# Mentally trying to sort out password<->Db scheme - how is this usually done?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, security

Okay so my problem is this:
Firstly, user access to the SQL database is controlled by windows authentication, but the app is doing a second check to set user privilege levels within the app.

1. When I create a new user in my WinForm client App it asks for a password which I then hash with a random salt, these data are then stored in the users table of my SQL database thusly:

users
username, firstName, lastName, pHash, pSalt, accessLevel etc.

1. When that user, in a later session, tries to log in he gives his password. I pull the salt out of the database and hash the given password.
2. Now this is my problem: I'm obviously insecure if I pull the hash from the database and compare it with the computed hash locally.

My App maintains a 'user' object that sets a flag for 'authenticated' and has a property that is set based on the 'accessLevel' column in the users table in the database.

There must be a usual way of doing this - or is my answer, you need to be using the SQL Server access facilities to do this not trying to re-invent it in managed code?

Comment: The client app shouldn't make the ultimate decision whether the user is allowed to do something. This should be the DB, or if you want to do it in managed code, an application server (layer in between). This is because the client app is running on the user's computer, so the user can instead use an app of their own design (which, for example, always sets "authenticated" to true) to bypass any check that is made in the client app.

Comment: Exactly, that was what I was worried about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right in that you can't trust the client to do authentication or authorization. That must be done on the server side.

In your case when you are accessing the SQL server directly from the client you would have to use SQL servers built in functionality for protecting different database objects.

That's usually quite hard to do in a good way though, so a more normal architecture is to create a separate server application such as a WCF service. The clients access the WCF service, which does the authentication and then is in charge of all database operations.

Comment: Right, so I need to create a 'layer' between my client program and my SQL database that handles the access?
And, ideally, I could run that code on the SQL Server machine itself. Meaning that it's not accessible by the user.